# Woocommerce login URL

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom page for login in Wordpress with Woocommerce integrated, and need that when a user click on my-account page, instead of using the login form from woocommerce, redirect to my custom login url.

my-account page only must be seen in case the user is logged in,else, I prefer the login and registering process be managed in /login/ and /register/ urls.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code:

```
function redirect_login_page(){
        if(is_user_logged_in()){
            return;
        }
        global $post;
        // Need for checking if this page equals wp-login.php
        
        // permalink to the custom login page
        $login_page  = get_permalink( 'CUSTOM_LOGIN_PAGE_ID' );
      
        if( has_shortcode($post->post_content, "woocommerce_my_account") ) {
            wp_redirect( $login_page );
            exit();
        }
    }

add_action( 'template_redirect','redirect_login_page' );
```

Comment: Amazing! works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

**Create Login page and add this code in content.**

> [woocommerce_my_account]

For Registration separate page use this extension.

[WooCommerce Simple Registration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-simple-registration/)

**Create registration page after active plugin add code**

> [woocommerce_simple_registration]